# ошибка в header php file_get_contents

Tags: php, файлы, header

Помогите пожалуйста решить данную проблему, очень буду благодарен за уделённое время.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Ну можно предположить, что geoplugin.net забанил ваш сервер